# SQLITE import records, export only new records

Tags: sqlite

I have records that will get imported every hour to a table.  The records are often duplicates.  I want to delete any duplicates, note which records are new and then copy/move/export them somewhere else.

How can I do this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet.  I'm new to it and learning at the moment.

Comment: Well, welcome on SO, you should read about this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: As I understand it, what you are suggesting will only remove duplicates from the query and not from the actual table, correct?  Example:

SELECT DISTINCT
 field2
FROM
 field2;

I want to remove the duplicates from the table.

Comment: Little me redirect you to an other useful page in Stackoverflow to ask your question in a better form : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: How about import all the records on the hour into a temporary table, do a delete on this table with rows matching the main table, then you have the new rows which you can now insert into to the main table and export, then you clear the temporary table before the next batch.

Comment: That's a great idea, Lasse.  I'm going to learn how to do that.  Thanks.  I've gotten the Python code to dump it into the SQLite db on a schedule now, so I'm off to a good start.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two tables that are the same.  I initially populate data into TableA and then copied everything from TableA into TableB.

`INSERT INTO TableB SELECT * FROM TableA;`

When new data streams into TableA, I go:

```
    DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT *
   FROM TableB
   WHERE TableA.field1 = TableB.field1);
```

And then, I do what I need to do with the data in TableA and then copy everything from TableA to TableB again.

`INSERT INTO TableB SELECT * FROM TableA;`

Repeat as often as new data streams into TableA and repeat.  This keeps only "fresh" data in TableA.  Please advise if there is a more elegant solution.

Thanks again.